# Same strategy, same payoff?

Tags: game-theory

In the context of game theory, I wonder if the following statement is true **for any game**, if so, how do we prove it.

If every player plays the same strategy in a given game, then the payoff must be the same for everyone.

Comment: Usually, payoffs are defined to be functions of the strategies, so the result is trivially true.

Comment: If everyone plays the strategy of marrying the first person who proposes, the payoffs will definitely not be the same for everyone.

Comment: I guess the question cannot be answered without a notion of sameness of strategies.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, i mean pure strategies in my question.

Comment: Take a two player game with strategy sapces $S_1=S_2=\{a\}$. Let $u_1(a,a)=1$ and $u_2(a,a)=0$. Then the payoffs differ even though both choose the same strategy.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, so i guess the above statement is true only if the game is symmetric as joriki pointed out below in his answer.

Comment: No, not only for symmetric games. $S_1=S_2=\{a,b\}$. Payoffs are given by $u_1(a,a)=u_1(bb)=u_2(a,a)=u_2(bb)=u_2(a,b)=u_2(b,a)=1$, and $u_1(a,b)=u_1(b,a)=2$. This game is not symmetric, but satisfies the criterion.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, this is true iff the game is symmetric. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_game):

> A symmetric game is a game where the payoffs for playing a particular strategy depend only on the other strategies employed, not on who is playing them.

Note that here "strategy" is used in the sense of "pure strategy"; players playing the same mixed strategy in a symmetric game will generally get different payoffs because of different random decisions.